# Evaluating the model in WEKA

Tags: performance, machine-learning, classification, weka

I have applied classification algorithm on dataset and came out with below stats:

```
Correctly Classified Instances         684               76.1693 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       214               23.8307 %
Kappa statistic                          0     
Mean absolute error                      0.1343
Root mean squared error                  0.2582
Relative absolute error                100      %
Root relative squared error            100      %
Total Number of Instances              898     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0         0          0         0         0          0.5      1
                 0         0          0         0         0          0.5      2
                 1         1          0.762     1         0.865      0.5      3
                 0         0          0         0         0          ?        4
                 0         0          0         0         0          0.5      5
                 0         0          0         0         0          0.5      U
Weighted Avg.    0.762     0.762      0.58      0.762     0.659      0.5  

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   d   e   f   <-- classified as
   0   0   8   0   0   0 |   a = 1
   0   0  99   0   0   0 |   b = 2
   0   0 684   0   0   0 |   c = 3
   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   d = 4
   0   0  67   0   0   0 |   e = 5
   0   0  40   0   0   0 |   f = U
```

I can understand much of the data however there is a problem interpreting the values since i am new to Weka:
1. Which error rate to report overall?
2. How to interpret if something interesting about the model?

Comment: It seems your ML model cant learn anything, only predict all the test intances to class c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) Overall error measure

The triplet **Precision**, **Recall** and **F-Measure** together is reported quite often because each number represents a different aspect of the model.

If would like to have a single number only then take **Percent (In)correctly Classified Instances**  or **Weighted Avg. F-Measure**.

The other error measures are also useful but they require deeper knowledge of statistics (which I'm lacking :-)

### 2) Something interesting about the model

From *Detailed Accuracy By Class* and *Confusion Matrix* you can see that the model is quite simple. It **classifies everything as class 3**. The error measures looks quite successful, but it is just because 76% of instances in the dataset have the class 3. The model corresponds with often used baseline algorithm called "most common class".

Answer (score 2):

The ROC area is also useful in terms of evaluating accuracy and interpreting how interesting a model is. Simply speaking, the true positive rate is plotted against the false positive rate and the ROC area is calculated as the area underneath this curve. A high ROC area, say 0.9 to 1, indicates that the model is very good at classifying instances, whereas a ROC area of 0.5 (as in your model) means that the model is no better at classification than a random method like flipping coins.